NET-SNMP: No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
I'm attempting an SNMP GET operation to retrieve an integer value. Specifically, I'm aiming to retrieve the integer value of the object NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleInteger located at the OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1.
The MIB is correctly configured and recognized. Confirming this, when I execute snmptranslate -IR netSnmpExampleInteger -On, I receive the following output: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.1.1.
Additionally, I've manually included the MIB in the snmp.conf file. However, I believe this step is unnecessary since it's a standard MIB.
Below is an excerpt from my snmpd.conf file:
# Views
#   arguments viewname included [oid]

#  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.2.1
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.4.1
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.4.1.9999

# rocommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-only access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid | -V view]

# Read-only access to everyone to the systemonly view
#rocommunity public 0.0.0.0/0
#rocommunity  public
rwcommunity public
#rocommunity private 127.0.0.1 .1
#rocommunity6 public

